# How to use the `ConstructorParameter` utility with types that accept generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to get the constructor parameter type out of a class. However, the class I'm pulling from accepts a generic type value.

Does anybody have any insight into how to accomplish this?

The error I'm running into:

```
ConstructorParameters<typeof (DictionaryClass<contentType>) >[0];
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                             Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'pathfinder_T' and 'number[]'.
```

Comment: Not supported curently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) combined with the `infer` keyword:

```
class Foo<T> {
    foo?: T;
}

class Bar {
    constructor(arg: Foo<string>) {
        // NOOP
    }
}

type ExtractFooType<P> = P extends Foo<infer T> ? T : never;
type foo = ExtractFooType<ConstructorParameters<typeof Bar>[0]>
```

Comment: The `const bar = ...` line is not needed.